# Share Azure VM Image with multiple subscriptions

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, vhd, windows-server-2016

I have created a generalized Windows VM image that have all the configurations I need to run my applications.

I would like to share it other members of my team that use different subscriptions.

I followed this tutorial from Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#create-a-managed-image-of-a-vhd-in-powershell

How can I give my team mates access to this image?

Answer (score 2):

As images are just blobs in your storage subscription, the other members of your
team would need to copy them from your storage account, create images from them
and then deploy the VMs.

A useful utility can be
[AzCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy),
further described in
[this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2013/03/31/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob/)
(from 2013).